# Selecting html elements with jquery based on div and some other attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html code:

```
<p class="test" data-id=1>Some Value</p>

<p class="test" data-id=2>Some Value</p>

<p class="test" data-id=3>Some Value</p>

<p class="test" data-id=4>Some Value</p>
```

How can I select a `<p>` element based on its `data-id`?

Comment: look at [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: `$('*[data-id="1"]');`

Comment: you should always put attribute values in quotation marks. just a good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the comments people. Its just hard to search the internet without knowing the exact terms.

Comment: What's the `div` in your title have to do with anything inside the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
alert($("p[data-id='1']").html());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S4y5T/)

[jQuery - Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: Thanks mate. How can I select a particular element with its class name and data attribute?  Im trying $('.test').data('id'=2); but its not working.